# sorting and filtering ListView with custom array adapter with two TextView?

Tags: android, android-listview

have an `ArrayAdapter` with two `TextView`.
when set it to `ListView` it is working correctly but when I sort it,
it sorts according to name but `TextView` which holds number doesn't change their position accordingly.
and if I don't apply sort and try to filter name with number then show only initial contacts rather show the contact which I want.

This is my custom adapter:-

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] name;
private final String[] number;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] name, String[] number) {
    super(context, R.layout.name_num_list, name);
    this.context=context;
    this.name=name;
    this.number=number;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_num_list, null, true);
TextView txt_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
txt_name.setText(name[position]);
TextView txt_num= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);
txt_num.setText(number[position]);
return rowView;
}

    }
```

this is my list activity....

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class ContactListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{


String phoneNumber;
String name;
String[] namePerson;
String[] phoneNumberP;
 ListView lv;
 EditText searchContact;
 CustomListAdapter customAdapter;
 ArrayList <String> aa= new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList <String> aa1= new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);
    searchContact=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_contact_search);
     lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    getNumber(this.getContentResolver()); 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    searchContact();
}

public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
{
    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      aa.add(name);
      aa1.add(phoneNumber);
    }
       phones.close();// close cursor

       phoneNumberP=aa1.toArray(new String[aa1.size()]);
       namePerson=aa.toArray(new String[aa.size()]);
       customAdapter= new CustomListAdapter(ContactListActivity.this, namePerson, phoneNumberP);


       customAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
          @Override 
          public int compare(String arg1, String arg0) {
              return arg1.compareTo(arg0);
          }
      });

           customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long arg3) {

}

private void searchContact() {
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     searchContact.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged( Editable name)
        {
            ContactListActivity.this.customAdapter.getFilter().filter(name);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

  }
      }
```

my xmls are...

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


     </LinearLayout>
```

and for list

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:id="@+id/preview6" >
           <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/main_ll_contactlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_black">
          <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_contact_search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"      
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
          </EditText>

          <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/lv"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               />

          </LinearLayout>
          </FrameLayout>
```

I take `FrameLayout` for my other works.

if any other idea then suggest me.

Comment: You have an arrayadapter for two sting arrays (names[] and phones[]) and you sort only the first one. You could better use only one string array (names_phones[]). Separate the name and phone number by some specila chars (like ===). Then sort. In getView split the string in name and phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem : 
you try to maintain two arrays in your custom adapter : `name[]` and `number[]`, however `ArrayAdapter` is designed to keep track of single array / list.

When you sort items with `customAdapter.sort` 
it will sort `name` array only and your `number` array will remain intact, thus numbers will be displayed at original positions, no matter how you sort names.

What you need is to maintain mapping between your `name` and `number` variables. You could use a HashMap for that. Another simple solution to bind them is to have your item as

```
class Item {
    String name;
    String number;
}
```

initialize your adapter with array `Item[]`; and sort this array by supplying custom comparator :

```
      customAdapter.sort(new Comparator<Item>() {
          @Override 
          public int compare(Item arg1, Item arg0) {
              return arg1.name.compareTo(arg0.name);
          }
      });
```