# Update content in ListFragment on menu click

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment with some data. I am trying to sort the content of my list depending on which item I select from the menu. How can I update the content of the list when I select one option from the menu? I don't want to create another fragment, I just want to sort by name or by date the info that I have in the list so when I click one item in the menu the list updates immediately depending on whether I click sort by name or sort by date.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_sort_by_name) {
        Fragment currentFragment =        this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Months, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And then I have the java class for the fragment:

```
public class EventsListFragment extends ListFragment implements     OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can update the sort for an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use a Sort (by comparator) or by Filter on array or custom adapter - depending on the complexity of the adapter object**

some examples and references:

- [Sort listview with array adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906464/sort-listview-with-array-adapter)
- [sorting and filtering ListView with custom array adapter with two TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262445/sorting-and-filtering-listview-with-custom-array-adapter-with-two-textview)
- [Android filter and sort ListView with adapter set during Async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387038/android-filter-and-sort-listview-with-adapter-set-during-async-task)
- [How to sort adapter (BaseAdapter) based on current its field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749666/how-to-sort-adapter-baseadapter-based-on-current-its-field)
- [Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)
- [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)
- [How could i filter the listview using baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720481/how-could-i-filter-the-listview-using-baseadapter)

basic example for array adapter:

```
Adapter.sort(new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);   //Your sorting algorithm
    }
});
```

*Item - class definition for adapter item

array adapter doc ref:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

complete solution for your case:

- http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-sort-ListView.htm